# Upon system restart, dconf editor doesn't save changes

Tags: touchpad, dconf, scrolling

I can use the dconf-editor to change my touchpad settings to natural scrolling, but upon system restart the settings get reverted. (But not on sleep or hibernate.) When I open the editor, the option is still orange indicating it has been changed. when I uncheck and recheck the natural scroll option, it is re-enabled. Is there a fix, or am I changing the wrong option? The path is org > gnome > settings-daemon > peripherals > touchpad > natural-scroll.

Currently running 13.10

Comment: I'm having similar issue. Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Also having this issue with 'autorun-never' in the 'media-handling' section of 'org->gnome->desktop'. I have some network volumes automount while at work, and it's really annoying to have to close the little autoruns every boot.

Answer (score 4):

> ## Lock down specific settings
>
> *cited from* [*GNOME Help/Sysadmin Guide/User Settings/Lock down specific settings*](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf-lockdown.html.en)
>
> To lock down a `dconf` key, you will need to create a `locks`
>   subdirectory in the keyfile directory. The files inside this directory
>   contain a list of keys to lock. Just as with the keyfiles, you may add
>   any number of files to this directory. Here is an example of what one
>   might look like:
>
> How to lock the default wallpaper
>
> 1. **First, set a setting, such as a default background which will be used    for this example.**
> 2. **Create a directory named** `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks`.
> 3. **Edit** `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/00_default-wallpaper`, **listing one key per line:**
>
>    ```
>    # prevent changes to the background
>    /org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-uri
>    /org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-options
>    /org/gnome/desktop/background/primary-color
>    /org/gnome/desktop/background/secondary-color
>    ```
> 4. **Update the system databases:**
>
>    ```
>    # dconf update
>    ```
>
> > As of dconf 0.7.4, lockdown is only supported on a per-key basis for
> >     performance reasons; you may not yet lock entire subpaths. There are
> >     plans to address this in future releases.

## Your Solution

For adding to your new `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/00_default-touchpad` file:

```
    # prevent changes to the touchpad
    /org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/touchpad/natural-scroll
```

[gnome](/questions/tagged/gnome) [dconf](/questions/tagged/dconf) [gsettings](/questions/tagged/gsettings) [lockdown](/questions/tagged/lockdown)

Comment: Thank you! This worked. It took me a minute to figure out exactly how to do it for the annoying autorun, but still works.