# dconf settings reset on restart session

Tags: gnome-shell, 18.10, dconf

I've modified `org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folder-children` to be equal to `[]` and whenever I reboot or log out, it gets reset to `['Utilities', 'Sundry', 'YaST']`. This is really annoying because I don't want any folders in my Applications Menu.

Comment: Isn't *YaST* something that isn't normally present in a Ubuntu system?

Comment: I have no Idea, it's a category in the GNOME 3 applications menu, and that's all I know. I don't have anything that uses it, though.

Comment: did you use dconf tool to make it? are the changes applied in the same session? after a logout or reboot only its comin back to default? are you the admin user?

Comment: I used dconf Editor to change it, they are applied in the same session. After logout or reboot, they reset. I have sudo permissions, but I'm setting for my own account.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upon system restart, dconf editor doesn't save changes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/439229/upon-system-restart-dconf-editor-doesnt-save-changes)

Comment: This seems lik a duplicate. See here how to [Lock down specific settings in dconf-editor](https://askubuntu.com/a/571032/813451)